# How to remove the duplicate items from the Taxonomy terms view in Drupal-6?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, ubercart, catalog, drupal-taxonomy

I am using Ubercart shopping cart for my site in Drupal. The website is restaurant website. For the Menu items, I have created 2 main categories as follows :

- Lunch
- Dinner

Now the main categories contains subcategories as follows :

- Ensalades
- Entremeses
- Platos Principales and so on.

Now Most of the subcategories are common to both main categories e.g Ensalades and Entremeses are present in both Lunch and Dinner category.

I have created a view for my product categories page to display all categories products.
Below is the attached screenshot of my views what I have done so far.
[image]

Its working fine until I add a item in both the catgories i.e Lunch and Dinner.

Suppose if I add item names Luis Salad in Lunch - Ensalades and Dinner - Ensalades category.

When I view the Dinner page it shows Luis Salad item twice in that page. First for Dinner category and second time for Lunch category as the items has been added to the both categories.

I just want to know is anything wrong in my view or I have created categories wrongly.

One way which will help this problem is to create a new item for each category. But that is not the right way as we cannot have one product to be treated as different product for different categories.
 Below I also attached my screenshot for my categories.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better way is to create two vocabluaries: One for main categories and second for food type.

- Main Vocabluary

  - Dinner
  - Lunch
  - ...
- Food type

  - Dessert
  - List item
  - ...

So in views you can just sort by two taxonomy terms. Easiest way to create two display pages for each main category.